# React duplica el resultado

Tags: javascript, reactjs

en mi app de **REACT** que consume de un **API**, los datos llegan bien pero al hacer un console sobre el resultado, que es una iteracion,  ***me duplica el resultado***.

Yo se que el **.map()** que utilizo ademas de la operacion devuelve un arreglo de los resultados, o eso creo

Pero no estoy seguro de donde vienen

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
// Importar cliente Axios
import clienteAxios from '../../config/axios';


function Clientes () {
    // Trabajar con el State
    // clientes = State
    // guardarClientes = Funcion para guardar el State
    const [clientes, guardarClientes] = useState({});


    //Query a la API
    const consultarAPI = async() => {
        // console.log('Consultando...');
        const clientesConsulta = await clienteAxios.get('/clientes');
        // console.log(clientesConsulta.data.clientes);

        // Colocar el resultado en el State
        guardarClientes(clientesConsulta.data.clientes);
    }

    //  Use effect es similar a componentdidmount y willmount
    useEffect( () => {
        consultarAPI();
    }, [] );


    function createArray(clientes) {
        if (clientes && clientes.length > 0) {
          return clientes.map(cliente => console.log(cliente)
          );
        }
        return null;
      }


    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2>Clientes</h2>
            {/* {console.log(clientes)} */}
            {/* {console.log(guardarClientes)} */}
            
            <ul className="listado-clientes">
                {createArray(clientes)}
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Clientes;
```

Muuchas Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Cómo te llega la información de la API? ¿Cuál es el resultado que obtienes? Me refiero a ¿dónde te das cuenta que está duplicado?

Comment: Hola  Kroneaux Schneider,  gracias por tu respuesta. Si, me doy cuenta cuando pongo a iterar un console.log(cliente) dentro del .map.Sí lo quito no sale ninguno. He avanzado un poco haber como va con la vista, y va bien , no lo duplica en ese caso. No obstante sigo en la brecha a ver como funciona esto :)))) Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Lograste solucionarlo? Tengo el mismo problema pero no doy con la solución